# FosElasticaBundle: multiple types in one index

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I need to build a multiple-entity search.

I don't want every T1, then every T2.

When I use `fos:lastica:populate`, I get an error:

> Rejecting mapping update to [search_dev] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [t1, t2]

My mapping:

```
fos_elastica:
   clients:
       default:
           host: %elastic_host%
           port: %elastic_port%
   indexes:
       search:
           finder: ~
           client: default
           index_name: search_%kernel.environment%
           types:
               t1:
                   indexable_callback: 'getEnabled'
                   properties:
                       id:
                          type: integer
                       name: ~
                   persistence:
                       driver: orm
                       model: AppBundle\Entity\T1
                       finder: ~
                       listener:
                          logger: true
                       elastica_to_model_transformer:
                          ignore_missing: true
               t2:
                   indexable_callback: 'getEnabled'
                   properties:
                       id:
                          type: integer
                       name: ~
                   persistence:
                       driver: orm
                       model: AppBundle\Entity\T2
                       finder: ~
                       listener:
                          logger: true
                       elastica_to_model_transformer:
                          ignore_missing: true
```

My service:

```
$search = $this->indexManager->getIndex('search')->createSearch();
$search->addType('t1');
$search->addType('t2');
$resultSet = $search->search($query);

$results = $this->modelTransformer->transform($resultSet->getResults());
```

Did I miss something? Can I map 2 types in 1 index?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a way to get products and categories and got the same error. It worked when I moved it around and made multiple indexes:

```
fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
  indexes:
    products:
      types:
        product:
          properties:
            ...
          persistence:
            ...
    categories:
      types:
        category:
          properties:
            ...
          persistence:
            ...
```

Comment: This is much more helpful than the other answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. In case it's still handy, would you be willing to post the PHP part of this?

Comment: I no longer have access to that code, but I had used their example as basis, worked pretty quick. And if you like answers on SO, dont forget to upvote them :)

Answer (score 3):

That's not related to Elastica, but Elasticsearch 6.0 : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html.

I have the same issue and didn't find an easy way to map multiple doctrine models in a single index for now.